# Программное изменение логических выражений

Tags: java, android

Есть класс, в котором множество условий проверяются на истину/ложь. Необходимо через интерфейс программы добавлять/изменять/удалять эти условия. Условия следующего вида

```
if(A[i] > 0 && (B[i+1] == 0 || C[i-4] <= 2))
    uu += "message";
```

Как реализовал. Новое условие вводится пользователем в формате *условие;описание;сообщение* и сохраняется в файл. Далее при помощи регулярных выражений и замены условия приводятся к такому виду

```
1 > 0 && (2 == 0 || 3 <= 2)
```

Затем, используя библиотеку [EvalEx](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx) получал истину или ложь. Всё работает, но время обработки данных увеличилось в десятки раз по сравнению с тем когда условия хранились только в классе. Так как данных проверяется очень много, такой способ не подходит.

Есть ли возможность изменять исходный код класса программно так, чтобы это работало на android? Есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Не уверен что подойдет для Android, но посмотрите на Drools: http://www.drools.org/

Answer (score 3):

А вы уверены что вам нужно именно изменение класса? Может для ваших целей стоит воспользоваться паттерном [спецификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))?

Comment: Мне нужно быстрое выполнение функции. Сейчас буду смотреть, что такое спецификация.

Comment: быстрое выполнение и кодогенерация вещи не совместимые.

Comment: Как я понимаю, класс бы было достаточно один раз сгенерировать, а не при каждом вызове функции. И это было бы быстро.

Comment: Всё-таки не понимаю как использовать паттерн. Пользователь вводит в текстовое поле условие. Java получает string. Далее как к паттерну приехать?

Comment: если условия поступают в виде строки то да тут не получится просто взять и сделать логическое условие, тут парсить строку надо не иначе, для парсинга можно воспользоваться паттерном [интерпритатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), а потом уже по необходимости либо строить спецификацию либо просто выводить логическое условие из полученного результата

Comment: Парсером уже пользовался, он тормоза и добавляет.

Comment: Это понятно, но парсеры бывают разные и выбора по большей части у вас нет

Answer (score 0):

Реализуйте собственный просто парсер/разборщик ваших логических выражений. Надо просто задаться грамматикой вашего языка (судя по всему он у вас есть в неформализованном виде).

Если совсем лень то можно тупо описать формальную грамматику вашего языка и сгенерировать парсер, например через [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) или [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

В итоге вы сможете анализировать на лету логические выражения - это всяко быстрее чем разбор через regexp'ы